# exception thrown while using .txt in file name

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am trying to run the following code in which i have to save my file as .txt...but whenever I click on 'Save' button..it throws an exception..

Also i want to know how could I save the contents of my textarea line by line in the txt file (including \n).

Here is the code

```
try
{
    int val = jfc.showSaveDialog(jf);
    int x =0;
    String line;
    if(val == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File fs=jfc.getSelectedFile();
        if(!fs.exists())
        {
            fs.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fs.getAbsolutePath()+".txt");
            BufferedWriter bf=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(ja.getText()));
            while((line= br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                x++;
                if(line.charAt(x)=='\n')
                    fw.write('\n');
                else
                    fw.write(line+"\n");
            }
            fw.close();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e2)
{
    e2.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot save file");
}

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at notepad$1.actionPerformed(notepad.java:100)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: The stacktrace clearly states that on line 100 of notepad.java there's an error (caused by trying to get a char out of index). Why are you incrementing `x` every line and using that to index characters? That won't work.

Comment: Indeed, it's not clear what `x` is meant to represent...

Comment: thnx. but what should i do to save my file in .txt format

Comment: It will be saved as txt format if nothing wrong happens with your variable x...
It looks like x is your line counter, but you are also using it to read char on each line. (BTW readline() will not return \n values, so it is useless).

Comment: For starters you should simply remove everything from the while loop and only do a `fw.write()`

Comment: There is no such thing as ".txt format". The OS doesn't give a sh* about a file's extension, it is just part of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Change your current code from

```
while((line= br.readLine())!=null)
{
    x++;
    if(line.charAt(x)=='\n')
        fw.write('\n');
    else
        fw.write(line+"\n");
}
```

to

```
 while((line= br.readLine())!=null) {             
     fw.write(line+"\n");
 }
```

Comment: its not working...its appending the text in same line.

Comment: But it removed your exception. If you need more lines add more \n

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the first char in the first line, the second char in the second line so on.

Try changing

```
if(line.charAt(x)=='\n')
```

to

```
if(line.endsWith('\\n'))
```

Also you should escape line ends. Use **\\n** instead of **\n**.

Comment: Do you expect anyone writing "\n" in the input field ?

Comment: if(line.endsWith('\\n')) : - not working...and yes i am expecting any one may write with "\n"

Comment: can you let me know the error you got with endsWith?

Comment: there is no error... but its appending the next line text to the previous line...